# How to select a textarea by it's type and parent div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, textarea

I need to select a textarea with jQuery and my selector code isn't working.

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="textareaContainer">
    <textarea>
this is text
    </textarea>
</div>
```

JS (onload):

```
jQuery("#textareaContainer > input[type=textarea]").val("");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EVvfT/

When the page is loaded, the textarea's value is not overwritten. Unfortunately I cannot set the id or class of the textarea, which is why I need to select it as the child of the div it's in.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply `textarea`:

```
jQuery("#textareaContainer > textarea").val("");
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EVvfT/1/)

If there's more than one `<textarea>`, you could use [**first()**](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first, [**last()**](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last or [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select any others in between.

Answer (score 1):

To only grab the first one:
`jQuery("#textareaContainer > textarea:first").val("");`

Answer (score 0):

You can select it like:

```
$('textarea > #parentId').val()
```

Alternatively:

```
$('textarea > div[class="something"]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the textarea and want to test to see if the parent is what you want it to be you can do:

```
var $textarea = $('#textarea'),
    $parent = $textarea.parent(),
    isGoodParent = $parent.is('#textareaContainer');

// isGoodParent is true if the textarea's parent matches the selector `#textareaContainer`
```